# Should I use a private static member function, or free function in an unnamed namespace?

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, static-members, unnamed-namespace

I've recently made a change stylistically and wanted to see how other c++ programmers felt about it and if there were any downsides to it.

Essentially, when I needed a utility function which doesn't need access to a given class member, what I used to do was something like this:

**file.h**

```
class A {
public:
    // public interface
private:
    static int some_function(int);
};
```

**file.cpp**

```
int A::some_function(int) {
    // ...
}
```

But more recently, I have been preferring to do something more like this:

**file.cpp**

```
namespace {
    int some_function(int) {

    }
}
// the rest of file.cpp
```

Here's my thought process:

- it's one less file the edit
- simply having the function be listed in the header file can hint at implementation details
  which have no need to be exposed (even if not publically available).
- if the prototype of the function needs to change, only one file needs to be recompiled.

The last one is the most compelling to me. So my question is: **are there any downsides to this?**

They are functionally equivalent for most purposes that I can think of. It kind of seems to me that a `private static` function can almost always be converted to a free function in an anonymous `namespace`.

**EDIT**: One thing that comes to mind is that a `private static` function would have access to `private` members if given a pointer to an object to operate on, but if that's the case, why not make it a non-`static` member?

What do you guys think?

Comment: I also do this quite frequently.  It's less of a hassle and I find it cleaner.  As for private members, I usually make these functions very explicit about what they need and decouple them from the class such that they don't need access to class internals.

Comment: Can somebody make me understand what the <anonymous namespace> in this context is good for? I'm curious and would like to learn about it...

Comment: @AudioDroid Quick answer: in this context it's the same as declaring the function as `static` (file-scope) and guarantees there will be no clash during linking with other global functions with the same name.  Long answer: you should ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the function is only used in one source file, it makes perfect sense to define it there. If nobody else is using it, it doesn't belong in the header.

As you say, it reduces dependencies and can potentially save some recompiles.

Comment: The key, of course, is the "only used in one source file".  Even before unnamed namespaces, I was using `static` functions in the source file in such cases.  (Today, even if the function is needed in more than one source, I'll declare it in a private namespace, in a private header, which is only included in the implementation files, and not delivered with the library.)

Comment: Sometimes there are a lot of static access to the class when implementing the anonymous namespace function approach and sometimes become odd too.

Answer (score 7):

I can't see any downsides to using an anonymous namespace. If you *can* code the function usefully without access to the class members, then you should, because it decouples it from the class itself (like how the standard algorithms work on iterator pairs).

Answer (score 7):

I started doing this several years ago and never found any real draw backs. Anything that the object uses, but doesn't itself change the state of the object and doesn't need to be used anywhere else, I like to put in an anonymous namespace in the implementation file.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, the only static functions I use are factory functions, like this

```
class Angle {
public:
    static Angle FromDegree (float v);
    static Angle FromRadians (float v);

    ...
private:
    Angle (float degree);
};
```

Anything that does not need private access is made a free function. Anything that is not part of the public interface is, if possible, not put in a public place (conforming to your new approach).

Scott Meyer's article ["How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation"](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197) roughly describes the same approach:

> ### Minimalness and Encapsulation
>
> In Effective C++, I argued for class interfaces that are complete and minimal. Such interfaces allow class clients to do anything they might reasonably want to do, but classes contain no more member functions than are absolutely necessary. Adding functions beyond the minimum necessary to let clients get their jobs done, I wrote, decreases the class's comprehensibility and maintainability, plus it increases compilation times for clients. Jack Reeves has written that the addition of member functions beyond those truly required violates the open/closed principle, yields fat class interfaces, and ultimately leads to software rot. That's a fair number of arguments for minimizing the number of member functions in a class, but now we have an additional reason: failure to do so decreases a class's encapsulation.
>
> Of course, a minimal class interface is not necessarily the best interface. I remarked in Effective C++ that adding functions beyond those truly necessary may be justifiable if it significantly improves the performance of the class, makes the class easier to use, or prevents likely client errors. Based on his work with various string-like classes, Jack Reeves has observed that some functions just don't "feel" right when made non-members, even if they could be non-friend non-members. The "best" interface for a class can be found only by balancing many competing concerns, of which the degree of encapsulation is but one.
>
> Still, the lesson of this article should be clear. Conventional wisdom notwithstanding, use of non-friend non-member functions improves a class's encapsulation, and a preference for such functions over member functions makes it easier to design and develop classes with interfaces that are complete and minimal (or close to minimal). Arguments about the naturalness of the resulting calling syntax are generally unfounded, and adoption of a predilection for non-friend non-member functions leads to packaging strategies for a class's interface that minimize client compilation dependencies while maximizing the number of convenience functions available to them.
>
> It's time to abandon the traditional, but inaccurate, ideas of what it means to be object-oriented. Are you a true encapsulation believer? If so, I know you'll embrace non-friend non-member functions with the fervor they deserve.

Comment: @Default: Thanks for the hint; I didn't found the exact quotes from the book again, so instead I added a related classic.

Comment: "Based on his work with various string-like classes, Jack Reeves has observed" – what work of Jack Reeves is he talking about? Unfortunately he didn't quote the source nor mention the title of that work :/

Comment: @SasQ: Just a wild guess, but I think this is one of Reeves' works: http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/CUJ/2001/cexp1907/reeves/reeves.htm

Comment: Either that or http://www.bleading-edge.com/Publications/C++Report/v9810/Column13.htm which I've just found.

Answer (score 5):

Private static non-const *variables* are useless to any code not in the .cpp, so I always use an anonymous namespace like that.

Static const variables may document constraints and expectations that are useful to client code, so they go in the header.

Static functions may need access to private data members, so they go in the header *if they have to*.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a unity build (i.e. #including all the .cpp files of the project into one compilation unit in order to speed up compile times), you'll risk name collisions with other functions in anonymous namespaces.

That's about the only downside I've found.

Answer (score -1):

The whole reason for static function as opposed to global function is that it accesses the private members of the class. If this is not true, use a free function. This analysis is not complete answer until we have all 3 alternative ways to do it:

free function:

```
void f() { /* cannot access private members of any class */ }
```

static function:

```
class A {
public:
   static void g() { /* can access private members of class A */ }
};
```

friend functions:

```
    class A {
    public:
       friend void h();
    };
    class B {
    public:
       friend void h();
   };
   void h() { /* can access private members of both class A and class B */ }
```

The real problem with how c++ does this is that the function call looks different:

```
int main() {
   f();
   A::g();
   h();
 }
```

Comment: well, this is required standard answer triggered by any mention of free functions, static functions or friend functions. It needs to be available to anyone using these functions.